# trigger doesn't increase static value

Tags: custom-object, visualforce, before-trigger, static

I have **Company** class with **static field total_amount**

```
public class Company{
    public String name = 'BazuBazu';
    public static Decimal total_amount = 6;
}
```

I have my **custom object** **Employee**.
I have my trigger:

```
trigger total_amount on Employee__c (before insert) {
 for(Employee__c emp : Trigger.New) {
    Company.total_amount += emp.annual_salary__c;
    emp.phone__c = '1111';

    } 

}
```

In my **custom controller** I call the getter method of total_annual:

```
public class opportunityList2Con {

    public String getTotal_amount() {
        return ''+ Company.total_amount;
    }
```

I know that trigger works because I can see that employee has a phone. 
But even if I add employee with annual_salary 100, total amount is still 6.
Any idea  where is the problem?

Comment: Static variables do not maintain changes across transactions. Each invocation of a visual force controller method is a separate transaction. Important piece that you did not show is where you are inserting the record and how it fits into this question